# How to mock nested classes in scala

Tags: scala, mocking, mockito, scalatest

I have a class that can be simplified as below

```
class my {
  val b = new subClass()
  def a () = "not mocked"

  class subClass {
    def ret () = "not mocked"
  }
}
```

I need some way to mock `my.b.ret()`

Comment: What did you try? What's not working?

Answer (score 1):

Would something along these lines work?

```
class my {
  val b = new subClass()
  def a () = b.ret()

  class subClass {
    def ret () = "not mocked"
  }
}

class your extends my {
  override val b = new nested()
  class nested extends subClass {
    override def ret() = "TA-DA"
  }
}
```

Running the following

```
val mine = new my
mine.a()

val yours = new your
yours.a()
```

prints either `not mocked` or `TA-DA` depending on which you instantiate.

You can play around with this code [here on Scastie](https://scastie.scala-lang.org/stefanobaghino/KGojLhElRX6Q1eRHiFmAVg/9).

Comment: I think OP meant a mock with mockito in order to apply assertions on the mock easily after.

Comment: Mmmh, right... I didn't notice the tags. Thanks! Hopefully this could be helpful for other readers who are just looking for ways to mock manually.